# Turn a homomorphic encryption scheme into one that doesn't have the homomorphic property

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

Homomorphic encryption is a form of encryption that allows computation on cipher-texts, generating an encrypted result which, when decrypted, matches the result of the operations as if they had been performed on the plaintext. The purpose of homomorphic encryption is to allow computation on encrypted data.

I understand about almost homomorphic and full homomorphic, but how can I turn a homomorphic encryption scheme into one that doesn't have the homomorphic property?

Comment: Please only use quotes for *actual quotes*, not for highlighting your question.

Comment: Generally, you can pad the plaintext message, for instance by using a one-way-function that depends on the full plaintext message. I'm however at a loss on how to write this down in formula's, so I hope fgrieu, Poncho or any of the other will help and write down an answer.